# Is it possible to use a residue calculation to solve the complex integral $ C_{MRB} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\Im(1+it)^{\frac1{1+it}}}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt $?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

For some insight, I looked at comments by @Brevan Ellefsen, but still wonder if this integral can be expressed more elementarily than just calling it $ C_{MRB},$ which is short for the [MRB constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRB_constant#:%7E:text=The%20MRB%20constant%20is%20a,of%20the%20constant%20in%201999.) which I first described as a sum at the end of the last millennium. There is no known closed-form expression of the MRB constant. With as slow as the series is to converge and as hard the integral is to calculate, a finite number of standard operations for the constant would be just glorious! [Here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/366628) is a summary of nearly a quarter century of evaluating it.

@Dark Malthorp had the insight to prove my suspicion as shown:
"

> Here are the details on how I used the Abel-Plana formula: Let $f(x) =  1-(1+x)^{\frac1{1+x}}$. Then we have $$ C_{MRB} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty
>  (-1)^n \left(n^{\frac1n}-1\right) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(1
> > (n+1)^{\frac1{n+1}}\right)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nf(n) $$ To apply
> Abel-Plana, we need bounds on $f(z)$. It doesn't quite satisfy
> Wikipedia's assumptions, but actually, it's pretty nice anyway, as
> $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x+yi) = 0$ for all fixed $y$, and it is
> bounded in the right half-plane. Then we use the alternating series
> formulation of Abel-Plana:\begin{eqnarray}
>   C_{MRB}&=&\sum_{n=0}^n(-1)^nf(n) =
>   \frac12f(0)+i\int_0^\infty\frac{f(it)-f(-it)}{2\sinh(\pi t)}dt\\
>   &=&\frac12 \cdot 0 + i\int_0^\infty \frac{ 1-(1+i t)^{\frac1{1+it}} 
>   -1+(1-i t)^{\frac1{1-it}} }{2\sinh(\pi t)}dt\\ &=&i\int_0^\infty \frac{ -(1+i t)^{\frac1{1+it}} +(1-i t)^{\frac1{1-it}} }{2\sinh(\pi
>   t)}dt \end{eqnarray} Because $(1+z)^{\frac1{1+z}}$ is holomorphic for
> $\Re z\ge 0$ and real-valued for real $z$ we know that $f(\overline z)  = \overline {f(z)}$. Because $\overline z - z= -2i(\Im z)$, this implies $$ C_{MRB} = \int_0^\infty
>  \frac{\Im(1+it)^{\frac1{1+it}}}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt $$ Strictly speaking,
> we cannot pull the imaginary part out of the integral, as the function
> $\frac{(1+it)^{\frac1{1+it}}}{\sinh(\pi t)}$ has a pole at $0$ and
> thus its integral doesn't converge. The imaginary part, however, is
> bounded for $t\in(0,\infty)$.

"

Is it possible to use a residue calculation to find a closed form for $$
C_{MRB} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\Im(1+it)^{\frac1{1+it}}}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt?
$$

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but $\frac{(1+it)^{\frac1{1+it}}}{\sinh(\pi t)}$ having a pole at $0,$ can we consider the possibility of evaluating $$ 2C_{MRB} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty
 \frac{\Im(1+it)^{\frac1{1+it}}}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt? $$  I found out Mathematica gives the following.

```
In[70]:= Limit[Im[(1 + I t)^(1/(1 + I t)) Csch[\[Pi] t]], t -> 0]

Out[70]= 1/\[Pi]

In[181]:= Residue[(1 + I t)^((1/(1 + I t))) /Sinh[\[Pi] t], {t, 0}]

Out[181]= 1/\[Pi]

In[236]:= NIntegrate[
 Im[(1 + I t)^(1/(1 + I t))/Sinh[Pi t]], {t, 0, Infinity}]

Out[236]= 0.18786

In[237]:= 1/2 - 1./Pi

Out[237]= 0.18169
```

This line of reasoning gives a nice set of approximations for CMRB, but nothing exact.

```
In[527]:= CMRB=NSum[(-1)^n (n^(1/n)-1),

{n,1,Infinity},WorkingPrecision->30,Method->"AlternatingSigns"]

Out[527]= 0.18785964246206712024857897184

Let p be the following partial approximation

In[544]:= p=((1/2-1/\[Pi])+1/(2 \[Pi]-1));

In[545]:= CMRB - 1/2 p

Out[545]= 0.00237470999999980600500193334

In[546]:= (-279/(485 \[Pi]) + p) - CMRB

Out[546]= -7.2407186775943961640*10^-10

In[547]:= (237471/50000000 + p)/2 - CMRB

Out[547]= 1.9399499806666*10^-16

In[548]:= (Pi^2 Sqrt[4187/10993830] + p)/3 - CMRB

Out[548]= 3.1221252470091*10^-16
```

A different line of reasoning follows, but its analysis, or how to improve its approximation (or even to determine whether that approximation is fully related to it) is beyond my power.

[image]

Here is a little more detail showing some symmetry, but I don't see anything exactly equaling CMRB here.
[image]
[image]
In[827]:=

```
CMRB/2 + NIntegrate[
  E/Pi t - Im[(1 + I t)^(1/(1 + I t))/Sinh[Pi t]]/
    Re[(1 + I t)^(1/(1 + I t))/Sinh[Pi t]], {t, 0, a}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] - (3078 p)/(7769 p + 3850)
```

Out[827]= 1.714*10^-19

Comment: I'm confused by the last line of your post... are you proposing a numerical answer of $1/2 - 1/\pi$? Working with more precision in mathematica, the integral does not seem to converge to this...

Comment: The  1/2−1/π can't be exactly the integral. I just noticed that it was close. I was wondering if the -1/pi is one path and something close to 1/2 is another that together equals CMRB. If nothing else, I would like to see how the residue theorem relates to this constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic everywhere, and thus has not residues. You've attempted to take the residues of a modified function where the imaginary part has been dropped, which indeed has a residue, but I don't see how to recover the original integral from this

Comment: The best I can think of is using the last form of the integral you wrote without the imaginary part and using some very clever rectangular contour (it blows up badly as you move along the imaginary axis, so no chance I see for any sort of circularish contour to work). Since it decays rapidly along the real line, we can use the fact the integrand is even to express it via a rectangular contour from $-n$ to $n$ up to $n + k$ back to $-n - k$ down to $-n$. However, this idea doesn't seem to pan out... I tried it with the natural value $k = 2i$ (where the first nontrivial residues occur)...

Comment: ... and while the residues were trivial, the resulting integral along the line $t + 2i$ bears no immediate relation to the original integral

Comment: Omg. What a difficult question. Bounty will burn.

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen, can you show me all you got on "The best I can think of " contour work? I would like to see if anyone can see any hope for it.

Comment: Does the [explicit imaginary part](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=E%5E%28%28t+Arg%5B1+%2B+I+t%5D%29%2F%281+%2B+t%5E2%29%29+%281+%2B+t%5E2%29%5E%281%2F%282+%281+%2B+t%5E2%29%29%29+Sin%5BArg%5B1+%2B+I+t%5D%2F%281+%2B+t%5E2%29+-+%28t+Log%5B1+%2B+t%5E2%5D%29%2F%282+%281+%2B+t%5E2%29%29%5D%2Ct%3Deulergamma) or $x=1+it$ help?

Comment: Also, you could write $\frac{\text{Im}(f(z))}{\text{Re}(f(z))}=\tan(\arg(f(z))$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While mathematicians try to crack this nut, here's a physicist's point of view. I will focus on how to calculate this integral,keeping things as simple as possible, probably approximately.

The imaginary part of $(1+it)^{\frac{1}{1+it}}$:

$$f(t)=(1+t^2)^{\frac{1}{2(1+t^2)}}e^{\frac{t\arctan t}{1+t^2}}\sin\left [\frac{\arctan t}{1+t^2}-\frac{t\ln(1+t^2)}{2(1+t^2)}  \right ]$$

Such a gem divided by $\sinh(\pi t)$ needs to be integrated from zero to infinity in so called closed form.

For a physicist, this is a hopeless case. But...

Some of the first terms of Taylor expansion of $f(t)$:

$$t-\frac{t^3}{2}-\frac{3t^5}{4}+...$$

Indeed, this expansion diverges for $1<t$

Nevertheless, we divide the first two terms of the expansion by $\sinh(\pi t)$, integrate from zero to infinity and use well known results:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^3}{\sinh(\pi t)}dt=\frac{1}{8}$$

Result:

$$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{16}=\frac{3}{16}$$

Absolute deviation from exact value is about $0.0004$

This is an example of that that we can use diverging series to compute values. It is only important to guess where to truncate the series.